# Incorrect total reputation for the day

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I should hope my basic math is not failing me and that my browser cache is not trying to screw with me. At the time of this post my reputation for the day is 15 fake internet points so far. However I see that I have two accepts answers. One was revoked and then mark as answer again.

[image]

Both of my answers in these questions are accepted right now. What about this am I not wrapping my head around?

Based on the picture I understood the order of events as

1. accepted answer "How to exclude sub folders"
2. unaccepted answer "How to exclude sub folders"
3. another accepted answer "Compare array with null elements"

Comment: 15 + 15 - 15 = 15 in my world. What are you expecting?

Comment: I would think that it should be 30 since both accepted answers are mine. Thats my issue. Perhaps a refresh time i'm missing

Comment: But you also had the unaccept, for -15. Was that answer not *previously* (on a different day) accepted, then revoked/reaccepted today?

Comment: Yeah. sorry about that didn't pay attention to the order. *hit self with mallet. I saw 3 hours for both and didnt know that I could see the time stamps.

Comment: I was hung up since I didnt see an event for the previous acceptance. I understand why now. I saw it in the picture as 1. accepted answer 2. unaccepted answer 3. another accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you expand the post and look at the timestamps (hover over them), you'll see that the unaccept event happened *first*. That means the user unaccepted an answer that was accepted on some other day, then re-accepted the answer about 20 seconds later. That caused a reversal of the previous event and then a new accept event was created.

Comment: Thanks for the __hover__ point. Didn't know that the specific time stamps we viewable that way